# Getting value of Dynamically created Spinner and EditText Views

Tags: java, android

I have a created a dynamic button that add a Spinner and EditText Views upon each click, I need to get the values of both fields.

```
public void addRow() {
    LinearLayout ingrediantLayout = findViewById(R.id.ingrediant_linear_layout);
    //add edit text
    EditText ingrediantEditText = new EditText(this);
    Spinner ingrediantSpinner = new Spinner(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ingrediantEditText.setLayoutParams(params);
    ingrediantSpinner.setLayoutParams(params);
    ingrediantEditText.setText("");
    ingrediantEditText.setHint(R.string.ingrediant_value);
    ingrediantSpinner.setSelection(0);
    //create an id for each view
    ingrediantEditText.setId(ingrediante_weight + 1);
    ingrediantSpinner.setId(ingrediante_type + 1);
    //add the views in order of appearance
    ingrediantLayout.addView(ingrediantSpinner);
    ingrediantLayout.addView(ingrediantEditText);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Ingredient Weight Id " + ingrediantEditText.getId());
    ingrediante_weight++;
    ingrediante_type++;

}
```

I want the ids to be set as follow everytime the addRow() is called

```
ingrediante_weight_1 | ingrediante_type_1
ingrediante_weight_2 | ingrediante_type_2
etc...
```

is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: May I ask why you even need to worry about the IDs?  I have dynamically added elements before to an activity, but in all cases I was able to do whatever I needed without knowing the ID, because I had a reference to the object itself.

Comment: Please elaborate what you want those IDs for e.g. you need to find them by those "ids" later on (if yes, use `setTag()`)?

Comment: Hi Tim, well how did you reference the object and add it's value to an arraylist?

Comment: Why you need IDs to be set in the string? what is the use of that ids then? Do you want to display it anywhere> or find them by those ids?

Comment: I just want to find them, i will try setTags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add the string as id for your view. Instead, you can use [setTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) and [getTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()). You can use it easily with something like this:

```
ingrediantEditText.setTag("ingrediante_weight_1");
ingrediantSpinner.setTag("ingrediante_type_1");
```

Though like @tim-biegeleisen says, it seems superfluous doing the above. Because you can handle them by adding all the dynamically added view to a list with something like this:

```
private List<EditText> mIngrediantEditTexts = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Spinner> mIngrediantSpinners = new ArrayList<>();

public void addRow() {
  ...

  EditText ingrediantEditText = new EditText(this);
  Spinner ingrediantSpinner = new Spinner(this);

  ...

  mIngrediantEditTexts.add(ingrediantEditText);
 mIngrediantSpinners.addd(ingrediantSpinner);

  ...
}
```

where you can access each item by the position as the id.

Answer (score 1):

*You can not add Strings as id of a view.* View class only has a method [setId(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)). But there is a way to handle this (Although in this way also ids will be handled with integers only, but you will have a way to give some meaningful ids (using string) to a view.

You can do this by declaring id into xml and use it into java code. Like below

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="ingrediante_weight_1" />
    <item type="id" name="ingrediante_type_1" />
</resources>
```

And while setting id programatically you can use these like

```
ingrediantEditText.setId(R.id.ingrediante_weight1);
ingrediantSpinner.setId(R.id.ingrediante_type1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tag for view like shown below

```
public void addRow() {
        LinearLayout ingrediantLayout = findViewById(R.id.ingrediant_linear_layout);
        //add edit text
        EditText ingrediantEditText = new EditText(this);
        Spinner ingrediantSpinner = new Spinner(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ingrediantEditText.setLayoutParams(params);
        ingrediantSpinner.setLayoutParams(params);
        ingrediantEditText.setText("");
        ingrediantEditText.setHint(R.string.ingrediant_value);
        ingrediantSpinner.setSelection(0);
        //create an id for each view
        //ingrediantEditText.setId(ingrediante_weight + 1);
        //ingrediantSpinner.setId(ingrediante_type + 1);

        //Code for setting tags
        ingrediantEditText.setTag(String.valueOf(ingrediante_weight + 1));
        ingrediantSpinner.setTag(String.valueOf(ingrediante_weight + 1));


        //add the views in order of appearance
        ingrediantLayout.addView(ingrediantSpinner);
        ingrediantLayout.addView(ingrediantEditText);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Ingredient Weight Id " + ingrediantEditText.getId());
        ingrediante_weight++;
        ingrediante_type++;

    }
```

we can set any object as tag to view, so we can assign interger or string value to any view as tag
This might help you
Happy Coding...

Comment: Thanks Er Pathak, I will use Tag instead of Id.